# Running Windows 10 inside container

Tags: windows-10

As I am running Ubuntu in Virtual Machine on Windows machine. is it possible to run *Windows 10* 64 bits inside a **Docker** container on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Example: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run Windows under the said scenario, given that your system has sufficient resources to support concurrent running of the operating systems.

Comment: Kindly write commands for running Windows 10 inside a docker container